# Cordova/Phonegap / iOS: ERROR: Plugin 'Plugin01' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

After I upgraded to Phonegap 5 I can't create a working plugin for old or new projects.

There are many such questions but most relate to version 3 that worked fine for me. Can't find good docs related to version 5.

I created I new test project, like that and still I can't make it working.

```
phonegap create test01 com.example.test01 Test01
phonegap platform add ios
phonegap plugin add ../test01-plugin01/
phonegap build ios
```

plugin.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="com.example.plugin01"
        version="1.0.0">

    <name>Plugin01</name>

    <!-- ios -->
    <platform name="ios">

        <header-file src="src/ios/Plugin01.h" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/Plugin01.m" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Plugin01.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface Plugin01 : CDVPlugin {
    NSString* callbackID;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;
- (void)test:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.test01" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test01</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.example.plugin01" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <plugin name="com.example.plugin01" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

index.html

```
            <button onclick="test01();">Test</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();

        function test01(){
            cordova.exec(null, null, 'Plugin01', 'test', []);
        }
    </script>
```

I can see `Plugin01.h` and `Plugin01.m` in Xcode when I open project in `Plugin` folder. I can run app on iPhone.

When I touch "test" button then I get following error:

```
2015-07-20 12:00:29.108 Test01[1925:1174928] ERROR: Plugin 'Plugin01' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2015-07-20 12:00:29.109 Test01[1925:1174928] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 159] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Plugin01","test",[]]
```

I can't execute my native code from WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the feature tag inside a config-file tag in the plugin.xml so it's added to the config.xml

```
<name>Plugin01</name>

<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Plugin01">
            <param name="ios-package" value="Plugin01"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <header-file src="src/ios/Plugin01.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/Plugin01.m" />

</platform>
```